# Script for changing the names of spaces in mission control

Tags: macos, applescript, spaces, mission-control

I want to change the names of the spaces in mission control. I have seen previews posts that said it is not possible, but there was an app that manage to do that (which is out of the App Store right now) so I am sure it is possible.

Anyone have an idea how to do that? Apple script or any other way.

Thank you!